# Where to get Java eclipse extention\shourtcut for getters setters generation?

Tags: java, eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts, pojo

So I started to write a POJO class, created public variables and now want to get getters and setters for them (folowing Java [Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html))

so I have for example something like

```
package logic;

import java.util.Set;
import java.util.HashSet;

public class Route {
  private Long id;
  private String name;
  private int number;
  private Set busses = new HashSet();
}
```

which eclipse extention and in it which shourtcut will create Getters and setters for me to get something like

```
package logic;

import java.util.Set;
import java.util.HashSet;

public class Route {
  private Long id;
  private String name;
  private int number;
  private Set busses = new HashSet();

  public Route(){
  }
  public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
  }
  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
  public void setNumber(int number) {
    this.number = number;
  }
  public void setBusses(Set busses) {
    this.busses = busses;
  }
  public Long getId() {
    return id;
  }
  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }
  public int getNumber() {
    return number;
  }
  public Set getBusses() {
    return busses;
  }
}
```

Comment: @Lord Torgamus The 2 current answers from myself and @Cyntech both result in a dialog box  where you can pick and choose which getters/setters you want to generate.

Comment: @Kevin, sorry, I either remember this from an old version of Eclipse or I used a different Eclipse method and assumed it was the same.

Comment: @Lord Torgamus not a problem, it *is* a fair point that you don't always want getters and setters for each member.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think this is availble by default using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd>  ( I may have set this shortcut myself)

Or go to the Source menu, and select the Generate Getters and Setters option.

You can modify the keyboard short cut (and many others) by going to

1. Window->Preferences
2. Expand the "General" option
3. Select the "Keys" option

Answer (score 5):

In Eclipse, right click on the source code and choose Source -> Generate Getters and Setters.

This will open a dialog box where you can choose which of the class members you want to generate for. You can also specify either getters or setters only as well as generating Javadoc comments.

I use this all the time, very handy function!